# Search LIKE json object in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

Suppose in my `sample_table` exist field `json_field` (stringified JSON object, has `property_1`, `property_2`)
How can i select like this request: `WHERE property_1 LIKE %VALUE_1% AND property_2 LIKE %VALUE_2%` without fetching all data and search with php?

P.S. Yes i know, that was mistake to keep json string in field

Comment: You have to do a mini tweak on your field that has this data, something like `field like '%property_1%value_1%property_2%value_2%'` but it can bring you wrong data since all json is in on field and if you have an array of then in only one registry it mess up things

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

If you want to get data in your script you have to fetch them. Building dynamic request with the arguments.
Something like :

```
"...WHERE property_1 LIKE '".$value_1."' AND property_2 LIKE '".$value_2.'";
```

Comment: maybe this was true in 2014, but at least as of MySQL 5.7, released 21 October 2015, you can use JSON_EXTRACT() + LIKE to search (-:

Comment: You know that it's more than 8 years old..

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with php, however a decent database interface should allow u to execute any select statement. So according to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html#json-column-indirect-index  you should be able to query based on properties inside a JSON type column.

Even using where col->"$.propertyName" = xxx would work.
Using like 'xxx%' prefix search doesn't seem to work correctly though.
But with the page linked above. You should be able to create a generated column on frequently searched field and create index based on it and search like regular column.

Answer (score 0):

basically JSON_EXTRACT() + LIKE + quote() (if you're using PDO) or real_escape_string() (if you're using mysqli)

```php
$db->query("SELECT * FROM sample_table WHERE
 JSON_EXTRACT(`json_field`, '$.property_1') LIKE "
 . $db->quote("%{$VALUE_1}%").
" AND JSON_EXTRACT(`json_field`, '$.property_2') LIKE "
 . $db->quote("%{$VALUE_2}%")
```